# FFmpeg: How can I burn subs and clip a video with only one line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I did spend a lot of time googling it and trying to figure it out, and this is what I have right now:

```
ffmpeg -ss 23:10 -copyts -i "test video.mkv" -c copy -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -sn -vf "subtitles=test video.mkv" "video.mp4" -y
```

I have the video name in quotes since I want the command to work with video files with spaces in the name. The problem is that it preserves the timestamps from the source video, so on VLC player, the time says 23:10 right when I start the video and the slider is near the very end of the 24 minute video. When I click on an earlier time on the slider, it goes back to 23:10 the start of the video. I don't want that, I want the timestamps to be sanitized and for the clipped video to have the correct duration.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` before the output URL.